# How to inject inital state in ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am implementing [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx) state management in an Angular 4 app. It was going well until I tried to "hydrate" the app state with the state previously saved in the browser local storage.

I have a question about the [Initial State and Ahead of Time Compilation section](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md) of `ngrx/store` documentation.  Specifically, what does the following line mean and how would I go about setting ("dynamically injecting at run-time") `initialStateFromSomewhere` to a state retrieved from browser local storage?

```
/// Pretend this is dynamically injected at runtime
const initialStateFromSomewhere = { counter: 3 };
```

Comment: what is the that you are looking for are you trying to set up the intial state the link you provided shows that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating your reducer, you provide the initial state for the store.

Assume you have a `FeatureState`

```
interface FeatureState {
  counter: number;
}
```

Now in your reducer you need to create initialState

```
const initialState: FeatureState = {
  count : 0;
}
```

This initial State will be supplied to the state in the `reducer`

```
export function reducer(state: FeatureState = initialState, action: Action): State {
```

Now, if you want to dynamically add the `initialState`, you can retrieve the `initialState` from the store and pass it in the `reducer`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I am missing.  I need to retrieve the `initialState` from localStorage. How do I then get this `initialState` in the `store`, and then get it out of the `store` so that I can pass it in the `reducer`?

Comment: So you don't need to get it from the store, you need to just create `initialState` which you can pass as a `default argument` for `reducer` `state` variable. Now the `initialState` you will create will get it's property from the `localStorage` instead of just defaulting them to `0` or `null`